# Cross-Compiling ROS fuerte for a Nao v4. roscore doesnt run

Tags: ros, nao, cross-compiling, roscore, nao-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I am using ROS fuerte compiled form source, NAO v4 and cross compilation with NAO toolchain.

Currently this configuration is compiled and running only on the pc (ubuntu 12.05), but I have this error when I run roscore on the nao.

nao [0] ~/ros-nao/ros $ roscore

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nao/ros-nao/ros/fuerte/bin/roscore", line 4, in 
import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Any suggestion?? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45345/cross-compiling-ros-fuerte-for-a-nao-v4.-roscore-doesnt-run/) by [LeonardoLeottau](https://answers.ros.org/users/3140/leonardoleottau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need python setuptools which contains the module pkg_resources.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1